# Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log n}{n}$ convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Problem**: Is it convergent or not ?$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log n}{n}$$
>
> **Solution**:$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {\log n}{n}=0$$
>
> So it can be convergent or divergent

Other tests are not looking good

please help

Comment: A more general result say that series of the form $\sum \frac{1}{n^{\alpha} (\log n)^\beta }$ converges if and only if ($\alpha >1$) or ($\alpha = 1$ and $\beta >1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or not.

Use the fact that $\frac{\log n}n\geqslant\frac1n$ for every $n\geqslant3$ and the fact that the harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1n$ diverges.

Answer (score 5):

Integral test
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac {\ln x}x dx = \left . \frac {\ln^2 x}2 \right |_1^\infty \to \infty
$$
therefore divergent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$\frac{\log{n}}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$$ for any $n > 2$. What can you say about $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For all $n\geq 3$, we have that $\log(n)\geq 1$. Use the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Cauchy condensation test